# Make FeatureCollection from Features in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, features

I try to add a list of Features into a FeatureCollection with ee.FeatureCollection but it raises the following Error: *

```
"FeatureCollection (Error)
Collection, argument 'features': Invalid type. Expected: List<Element>. Actual: List<List<Object>>"
```

I don't understand the difference between Object and Element. It is necessary to convert the single Features Object into an single Feature Element?

```
var s2aprop = ee.FeatureCollection([
ee.Feature(s2a_p.aggregate_array("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE"),{name:'Cloudy_Percentage'}),
ee.Feature(s2a_p.aggregate_array("PRODUCT_ID"),{name:'Product_Id'}),
ee.Feature(s2a_p.aggregate_array("SENSING_ORBIT_DIRECTION"),{name:'Orbit_Direction'}),
ee.Feature(s2a_p.aggregate_array("SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER"),{name:'Orbit_Number'}),
ee.Feature(s2a_p.aggregate_array("SNOW_ICE_PERCENTAGE"),{name:'Snow_Ice_Percentage'}),
ee.Feature(s2a_p.aggregate_array("VEGETATION_PERCENTAGE"),{name:'Vegetation_Percentage'}),
ee.Feature(s2a_p.aggregate_array("WATER_PERCENTAGE"),{name:'Water_Percentage'}),
ee.Feature(s2a_p.aggregate_array("UNCLASSIFIED_PERCENTAGE"),{name:'Uncalssified_Percentage'}),
ee.Feature(s2a_p.aggregate_array("SPACECRAFT_NAME"),{name:'Spacecraft'})
])

var s2aprops = ee.FeatureCollection(s2aprop)
print (s2aprop)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca44d644303c7212c4a11e4c00f752a9
Line 161-174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the return value of `aggregate_array()` is an `ee.List()`, which you can discover by printing it (the docs are not obvious about this).  The [`ee.Feature` constructor](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eefeature) expects an `ee.Geometry` and optionally properties.  You're not supplying that, which is why it's not working.  Here's an example of how to fix that:

```
var s2aprop = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null, {
    name: 'Cloudy_Percentage',
    array: s2a_p.aggregate_array("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE")
  })
```